# ls doesn't work in mobaxterm local terminal

Tags: windows-10, terminal, ls, mobaxterm

I'm having a strange issue running mobaxterm v20.2 on Windows 10:

I am unable to use `ls` to see the contents of the local directory. For example, in this screenshot, the output of `ls` is empty, but the following `cd` works fine.

[image]

`which ls` also returns empty output. I do not have this error when I ssh from mobaxterm onto a remote machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what changed, but I reinstalled mobaxterm and ls seems to work again.